# Regex capturing in-between urls

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm new to regex, and I'm trying to capture a url such as `http://www.url.com/part1/part2` such that it returns `['url.com', 'part1', 'part2']`. Could someone help?

Comment: remember when tou post a regex question to specify you programming language and provide some code you tried, because "please solve that problem for me" is off-topic here

Comment: A clarification for "please specify language": there are differences between the various implementations of regex, so a regex that works on one system doesn't work on another.

Comment: Do you really need a regex? Your environment may have other components specifically for this, like [Uri class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) for .Net

Answer (score 0):

**PATTERN**

```
(?:http|https):\/\/(?:www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5})|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5}))(?:\/([^\/]+))(?:\/([^\/]+))
```

output:

```
['url.com', 'part1', 'part2']
```

**REGEX PATTERN EXPLAINATION**

1. `(?:http|https)` match either `"http"` or `"https"`
2. `:\/\/` match `"://"`
3. `(?:www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5})|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,5}))` match either `"www.url.com"` or `"url.com"`  and captures `"url.com"`
4. `(?:\/([^\/]+))` match `"/part1"` and captures `"part1"`
5. `(?:\/([^\/]+))` match `"/part2"` and captures `"part2"`

Comment: this regex works for python, i will delete it if it isn't compatible with your programming language, but you didn't specified it